# matplotlib fetch historical works when start year 2015 but not 2016 ?

Tags: matplotlib

want to get just a single day ( last trading day) from yahoo finance using matplotlib BUT I get an error on the code below. I REALLY can't see why can anyone help please?

```
import datetime
import matplotlib.finance as finance

start_date       = datetime.date(2016,8,1)
today = end_date = datetime.date.today()
ticker = 'GE'
fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker,start_date,end_date)
```

the error thrown is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/dave/Desktop/development/1 10 16 mp single test.py", line 
   13, in <module>
    fh = finance.fetch_historical_yahoo(ticker,start_date,end_date)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/matplotlib/finance.py", line 
431, in fetch_historical_yahoo
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url)) as urlfh:
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 161, in urlopen
   return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
   File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 470, in open
   response = meth(req, response)
 File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 580, in http_response
   'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 508, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 442, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
    File "/usr/lib/python3.4/urllib/request.py", line 588, in 
  http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
 urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

Comment: Your start date is in the future, so the page doesn't exist (hence 404).  `datetime.date(2016,8,1)` is the 1st August 2016.

Comment: at times like this I want to just hide under my desk and rock back and forth. I have been staring at this for three days now! YOU are a great man and I thank you. You have many many many karma points. Seriously thank you from a person that should have their keyboard taken away from them.

Comment: Don't beat yourself up - we've all had moments like that :)  Glad I could help.